# Define a view into non-default(current) namespace

Tags: kdb, k

According to [How is a view defined](https://code.kx.com/q/learn/views/#how-is-a-view-defined)

> Views and their dependencies can be defined only in the **default** namespace.

Also `q` has a command [\b](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syscmds/#b-views):

> Syntax: \b [namespace]
>
> Lists dependencies (views) in namespace. Defaults to **current** namespace.

According to this I guess that it is possible to create a view not only into the default namespace:

```
$ q
KDB+ 3.6 2019.04.02 Copyright (C) 1993-2019 Kx Systems
m32/ ...
q)\d .jar
q.jar)v::x+1
q.jar)\d .
q)`. `v
x+1
```

but the view was created in `.` namespace.

So is it possible to create a view in a non-default(current) namespace for somehow? If no, why is there an argument for command `\b [namespace]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on what you call a namespace. The official q documentation on this topic is vague if not misleading. For example, a page describing the system command `\d` [reads](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syscmds/#d-directory):

> `\d (directory)`
>
> Syntax: \d [namespace]
>
> Sets the current namespace (also known as directory or context). The
>   namespace can be empty, and a new namespace is created when an object
>   is defined in it. The prompt indicates the current namespace.

As you can see, the optional argument is called a *directory* on the first line but it becomes a *namespace* on the second. Which, as we learn from the third line, is "known as context."

However, the three words -- namespace, directory and context -- can be used interchangeably in some, but not all, cases. Defining a view is one such case where the distinction between directories and namespaces is important.

Due to the lack of clarity in the official terminology let me refer you to a great book ["Q Tips: Fast, Scalable and Maintainable Kdb+"](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tips-Fast-Scalable-Maintainable-Kdb/dp/9881389909) by Nick Psaris. Nick distinguishes a subset of namespaces that begin with a "." and calls them and only them directories. In his terminology all directories are namespaces, but not all namespaces are directories.

It turns out that directories have limitations; in particular, they can't contain views. But a less known fact is that namespaces that are not directories can:

```
q).my.dir.v::x+1 / a (failed) attempt to create a view v in a directory
'x
  [0]  .my.dir.v::x+1
q)my.ns.v1::x+1   / v1 is defined in a namespace
q)your.ns.v2::x-1 / so is v2
q)\b
`symbol$()
q)\b my.ns
,`v1
q)\b your.ns
,`v2
q)x:41
q)my.ns.v1
42
q)your.ns.v2
40
```

Comment: Wow! I could only dream about such details and explanation! Thank you. Recently got my copy of Nick Psaris book, just started reading.